# Adding an image from css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have tried to add image to a footer div, but no works this what i have tried:

html:

```
<footer>
 <div class="imagenFooter" style="background-image: url(&quot;./images/footer-bg.jpg&quot;);"></div>
 <div class="footer-fluid" itemscope="" >
  <div class="container">
   <img class="logo_footer" alt=""><span class="direccionFooter" itemprop="address"></span>
   <nav class="enlacesFooter">
```

is suppose that image have to be shown in Image footer, i have tried this in css but no works.

```
.imagenFooter {
    background-image: url('/images/footer-bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I have to add the image from css only. I appreciate help..

Comment: have you tried setting a fixed min-width and min-height? do you see the element? try setting the background-color to pink to see the element, then work on the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not see the image, because there's no content in your `<div>`, so try to add padding(play with the value, because i don't know the size of your image), and don't forget to add `!important` to override the image in your HTML , try the code snippet below:

```css
.imagenFooter {
    background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/500x100')!important;
    padding-top: 20%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
 <div class="imagenFooter" style="background-image: url(&quot;./images/footer-bg.jpg&quot;);"></div>
 </footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
 display: none:
```

With display: none you wont see anything

Comment: <div class="imagenFooter"></div>

Comment: Remove the style

Comment: the idea is achieve it from css, without touching html structure

Comment: background-image: url('/images/footer-bg.jpg') ! important; add ! important at the end... If that not work then your url should be wrong